# Dialectric water heater connection

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, corrosion

I noticed a lot of corrosion around the connection between the nipples coming out of my water heater and the flex connectors.

[image]

The nipples are regular galvanized steel. Is this corrosion of dialectric nature because the other end of the flex connectors goes into copper pipe? Do I need to use special (dialectric) nipples to prevent this and could this be the cause of a spot leak I just got in one of those (cold inlet) flex connectors? There is no corrosion on the water heater side of the nipples.

Comment: I’m those look like regular galvanized nipples to me notice the rust in the threads. Galvanized steel pipe rusts where it is threaded because the zinc coating is removed.

Comment: I meant galvanized, sorry @EdBeal. corrected

Comment: I would say the right side looks like it could be is there a insulator like on the left pipe? It could have been a small leak also.+

Comment: there is but you can't see it because it's covered in dust

Comment: Is that the hot side also? On the right.

Comment: right is cold, left is hot.

Comment: I was thinking the heat could have caused leakage but that’s not it.